# Two function starts with Jquery not working

Tags: jquery, joomla

I have two function that starts like this

function 1:

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('.fancypantsaccordionholder').accordion({
        oneOpenedItem:true,
        speed:300,
        scrollSpeed:300,
        open:0          
    });
});
```

Function 2

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#sidepanel_jt').tabSlideOut({
       tabHandle: '.handle',                            
       pathToTabImage:'',
       imageHeight: '',                               
       imageWidth: '',                                    
       tabLocation: '<?php echo $panel_position;?>',                             
       speed: <?php echo $speed;?>,                                       
       action: 'click',                                 
       topPos: '<?php echo $topposition;?>px',                               
       fixedPosition: true                          
    });
});
```

but its not working with this two same jquery function name if i place $ in one function even though its not working.

Please help guys.

Comment: Wording is slightly awkward, do you mean the code you've posted *does* work, but if you replace `jQuery` with `$` it stops working?

Comment: Any error in the console?

Comment: Can you confirm that my assumption in my previous comment is correct? I'd like to edit the question to make it clearer, but I don't want to do that until you've said that's what you definitely meant.

Comment: Code I have post is not working on same page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick Google search suggests that jQuery isn't the only JavaScript framework being used by Joomla, and that it also uses MooTools - I don't have any experience with Joomla myself so I can't confirm this. If that's the case then jQuery is likely in "no conflict" mode, and `$` won't be mapped to the `jQuery` function.

What you could do is this:

```
(function($) {
    // your code here using $ in place of jQuery
})(jQuery);
```

That's an immediately invoked function expression, which passes `jQuery` as an argument to the `$` parameter. The result is that it creates a closure inside of which `$` and `jQuery` will be the same, even though they aren't outside.

Answer (score 0):

are you using more libraries? looks like collision to me.

Try wrapping your code in this:

```
(function($) {
  //your code
})(jQuery);
```